# iOS Test app on device, two differing regions

Tags: ios, xcode

In order to test an app I am building for a local client I need to get the iOS dev account for $99 obviously.

I have two Apple Ids. One for USA and one for South Africa, where the client is based.

If I get the developer account for the US profile can the app be published by the client under the South African store, when it gets to that point that is.

Do I simply provide the Source Code to the client or would it be simpler for them to get their own account and add me as a developer, not sure how this works for people with Apple IDs for differing regions.

In addition to this question, is it not possible for me to simply test the app on my own iPAD and iPhone without the $99 requirement and when the app is ready to later be added to the clients team on their development account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only test in simulator, without a payed developer account. But in 99% of cases that's enough. There are very few cases where a device is really needed. Of course the final testing should be done on a real device.

As far as i know you can publish apps from one developer account to the whole world. You do not need multiple accounts for other continents.

Comment: Hey, I am having a very similiar problem concerning the regions, I have an american Apple ID, and am developing something for my client in Brazil. If I register for the program in my american account, could I still publish the app in the Brazilian App Store? Do you have any reference for this? :)

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Hi, you can have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html "...Offer your free or commercial apps to millions of iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch customers around the world...." So i'm pretty sure, that you need only one account ;)

Comment: this should be helpful too :) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/1_Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Yes. Your app will be available in all stores (some categories might not be available in all countries, though). Reference: I have apps in the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You can test you app on a device without having an appropriate profile. All you should do - connect the device, go to Organizer, open Devices tab with your device and press "Use for development".

And about other question, I think it would be better if a client had his own account and connected you to it.

Comment: You can only register devices for development, if you are in a payed developer program.